# Starting a WPF Business Application From Scratch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am wondering whether there's a good tutorial that walks you through the development of a full business application that is comparable to the real ones. I have learned the basics of C#, WPF, and programming and web development in general. All the books I have read only shows the syntax and code snippets but very rare shows you the development of a full business application from planning to testing to deployment.

What is the first step when creating a business application using C#/WPF? I know I need to have a plan first. Should I use UML?

What methodologies or techniques should I consider when starting to code. I have read about Domain Driven Design but there is also MVVM patterm. Which one should I use? Should I learn both of them.

I am currently searching for a work in .NET but I really need to know how the developer's workflow in a real life software development team. I have found some books that walks you through the creation of a full software such as Wrox's Problem-Design-Solution books. Does the content of this book comparable to the workflows of a real-life software development?

Thanks a lot in advance and I hope I can find an answer as I am planning to practice my skills to be ready in a corporate environment.

Comment: You need a business case first. There can be no plan if you don't know what you're planning for. Design patterns, technologies, quantities of caffeine - all this crystallizes after you know what you are required to achieve.

Comment: I am planning to create a personal project (which I can use to find a job where I can get real experience) and I hope I can do the planning. Since I have no experience, I don't even know how to start planning. Are there any tips on how to do that? Thanks. I don't have any relatives or friends that's in the programming field so I am really on my own right now.

Comment: Start by solving issues on this site, that will help you tremendously.  I come here when there is nothing going on so I can challenge myself and avoid boredom.

Comment: Start small, if you don't have any previous professional experience pick something from you school/personal life. Think of something you could improve in your every day routines, then think if this could be achieved using software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, the platform is irrelevant at this point.  If you were doing a winform or a web app, would you use UML?  If so, then you would also use it in a WPF.  If not, fuggedaboutit.

The first step is to careful gather business requirements.

The methodologies or techniques you should consider when starting to code will be handed down to you by the lead of the project.  You sound very inexperienced, so the decision will not be up to you, most likely.  Every business is different.  Heck, every project is different.  You may use a different methodology on each of your first 5 projects.  Brush up on them, read what you can, but you will always have a learning curve to climb.

You don't need to learn every methodology or paradigm.  Learn as you go.  Understand the basic premises of a few, especially the standard waterfall, but don't deep dive until you get assigned to a project.  Most places I have been don't follow their own methodologies anyway.  It's one of those "The Sabbath was made for man, not man for the Sabbath" type things.  Organizations will deviate for a slew of reasons.

This is the book I had in college.  It has served me well.  You car order it for $0.33.  Ain't that something.  [http://www.amazon.com/Software-Engineering-7th-Ian-Sommerville/dp/0321210263/ref=sr_1_25?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1342506249&sr=1-25&keywords=software+engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321210263)

Good luck in the field.  Just dive in, and work hard.  You should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Yes I have that book and planning to read it. Is it a mistake to finish a book that focuses in a programming language rather than reading a software engineering book?

Comment: No, just don't take everything in the SE book as gospel.  Remember, "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is."  You will throw out a lot of that stuff when you get into the real world.  Accept this answer if it has helpful to you.